# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer dynamic location value : The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I'm extending `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in order to handle in a dynamic way the location attribute field. This works perfectly if I use full filepath, for example

```
D:/TFS/M/V14/Customisations/custom_extensions/app/src/main/resources/bll_db_connection.properties
```

But if I am using relative file path (starting from application classpath) I am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: bll_db_connection.properties
(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: Show me ur Bean configuration

Answer (score 0):

ok it was matter of Working directory field in Jboss tools window
now it is ok